# How do I sort a list in ascending order using a specific column, without using a build in function? (Python)

Tags: python, list, csv, sorting

I have imported a CSV file to a list in python containing animal data with the following columns:

```
Sanctuary Identification,Type,Breed,Vaccinated,Neutered

P23533,Cat,Persian,Yes,Yes

P43533,Dog,Poodle,Yes,No

P18754,Dog...
```

The data appears in the following format:

```
[[P23533,Cat,Persian,Yes,Yes],[P43533,Dog,Poodle,Yes,No],[P18754,Dog...]]
```

I would like to sort the list in ascending order of their Sanctuary Indentifaction, i.e:

```
P1111, Cat, ..
P2222 Dog, ..
P3333.. etc
```

I cannot use any build in libraries, can anyone suggest how I might go about this?

Comment: Just search for a sort algorithm online, implement it and apply it. That's what I would do.

Comment: `sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0])` or `import re;sorted(y, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x[0]).group()))`

Comment: The `sort` and `sorted` functions do not require imports. They have an extra argument of `key` you can use to determine what to sort by (in your case it should be something like `key: lambda row: row[column_index]`)

Comment: Take the List index one by one, for each index, take first element and then compare to the next index of the first element, `like Bubble Sort Implementation`.

Comment: *"I cannot use any built-in libraries"* Also known as "This is homework"

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the nested list using `sorted` built-in function, then pass in the first column as the key to be sorted. Below is the example.

```
In [1]: my_list = [["P23533","Cat","Persian","Yes","Yes"],["P43533","Dog","Poodle","Yes","No"], ["P1111","Asd","Test","
   ...: Yes","Yes"]]

In [2]: sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0])
Out[2]:
[['P1111', 'Asd', 'Test', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
 ['P23533', 'Cat', 'Persian', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
 ['P43533', 'Dog', 'Poodle', 'Yes', 'No']]
```

Alternatively, you can use `pandas.read_csv` to load your csv into `DataFrame` object, then use `sort_values` function:

```
In [10]: df.sort_values(["SanctuaryID"]).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[10]:
  SanctuaryID Animal     Type Col4 Col5
0       P1111    Asd     Test  Yes  Yes
1      P23533    Cat  Persian  Yes  Yes
2      P43533    Dog   Poodle  Yes   No
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have applied the code you suggested but I am still getting an unordered list when printing. Can you take a look at what might be wrong?


```

  with open("PETS.csv", "r") as pets_file:
    pets_file_reader = csv.reader(pets_file)
    for row in pets_file_reader:
      pets.append(row)


  sorted(pets, key=lambda x: x[0])
  for row in pets:
    print(row[0])

```

Comment: `sorted` is just a function which return new object (not in-place sorting), so you need to overwrite your `pets` variable (i.e. `pets = sorted(pets, key=lambda x: x[0])`,or you can create a new variable

Comment: @KurtisDunphy Can you accept this as answer so it'll be useful for someone else reading this?